# Using a question as information repository

Tags: discussion

[This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34786305/steps-to-build-static-standalone-qt-application-on-windows-using-msvc-or-mingw) simply uses it as an information storage vehicle, and even starts the post with:

> This is just a remember. After one week struggle building static/standalone QT application on windows, I finally succeed. Here are the steps, missing any steps will result a failure.

I feel like this needs flagging but I don't know what to flag it with.

Should I flag it for closure at all? Am I completely wrong here?

These are the options, none of them seem to be "this isn't a question"
[image]

OFf Topic Because Options... again same issue?
[image]

Comment: I have close voted as _unclear what you are asking_.

Comment: Is StackOverflow a place to create "questions" that aren't questions? There is no question in the above post it is simply a list of instructions on how to build something. If the answer to this question is no, then what do I flag it for closure with?

Comment: IIRC the flagging dialog provides the same reason when choosing the off-topic category.

Comment: I've added a picture of the options that I have, which is the correct one?

Comment: added list, still unsure...

Comment: Sorry mis-spotted: _unclear what you asking_ should be the choice from the first dialog.

Comment: It's quite clearly not a question though. The user states that in their first sentance. It was never intended to *be a question*

Comment: So that doesn't imply this close reason? I think the OPs statement clearly qualifies for this close reason.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Tbh the meta effect means it's received more attention than it would have in the `[opencv]` tag anyway and is going to get sorted but it's good to know for the future.

Comment: If you need help with close voting, either to decide on the best fitting reason or get some help in low traffic tags you can drop a support request in the [SOCVR](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) chat room.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately can't access chat at work though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have flagged as "should be closed" > " unclear what you're asking". Cause this is no question.

The author could explain his problem as a question in detail. What he tried and what goes wrong for example. And after this he could anwswer his question by this step by step guide as he already did.

When I have a question I post it. And sometimes I have the answer before anyone else has replied, then I don't delete my question. I answer it by myself. But in this case it is clear for the community what the problem was and how I have solved it.